# Perl split a string

Tags: perl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$command="lscpu | grep -i Architecture";
#$arch = system($command);
@SplitArch = split(/:/, system($command));
print @SplitArch[1];
```

The result I get is:

```
Architecture:          x86_64
```

I was hoping that the only thing that would display is:

```
x86_64
```

Comment: After your split statement, put this print statement to help figure out what is up...`print "\n\t-- $_" foreach(@SplitArch);`  That will spill the contents of the array in the console, making it obvious why your code isn't working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesn't do what you think it does. [The `system` function](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) runs the command and returns its exit status; so in your case, this:

```
system($command)
```

prints `Architecture: x86_64`, so this:

```
@SplitArch = split(/:/, system($command));
```

prints `Architecture: x86_64` and sets `@SplitArch` to `(0)`.

`print @SplitArch[1]` then prints nothing, because `@SplitArch` has only one element. (By the way, you probably meant to write `$SplitArch[1]` rather than `@SplitArch[1]`, but that's neither here nor there.)

Since you apparently intend to capture the output of `$command`, use [`` `...` `` or `qx/.../`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#qx/STRING/) instead:

```
@SplitArch = split(/:/, `$command`);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the output of a command, you should use the `qx{}` operator:

```
my @SplitArch = split /:/ qx{$command};
```

And to print the value at array index #1, you should use the `$` Sigil as you expect a scalar value:

```
print $SplitArch[1], "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the return value of System is the exit value of the command, not the output.

You should perhaps do:

```
$output = `$command`;
@SplitArch = split(/:/, $output);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Explanation already given —  `system` doesn't return what you think it does — I'm just providing an alternative solution.

```
open(my $LSCPU, '-|', 'lscpu') or die $!;
while (<$LSCPU>) {
   chomp;
   my ($key, $val) = split(/:\s*/, $_, 2);
   if ($key eq 'Architecture') {
       print "$val\n";
       last;
   }
}
close($LSCPU);
```

Advantages:

- Exits ASAP.
- Doesn't involve the shell.
- Involves one less external program aside from the shell.
- More precise matching of desired line.